# video calling through sipdroid

Tags: java, android, sip

i am trying to call from one android phone to another android through sipdroid app. and its work fine when i only do audio call but when i try for video call its doesnt work fine and i am using Pbxes.com server.
  i have my own wifi server. when we try to connect with this server it connect well and i am able to do audio calling...but when i tried for video call its doent even open in another mobile..

so plz help me what should i do to make video call with my own server. 
thanks in advance

Comment: which server are you using ? does it actually support video calls ? probably need to play with server settings a bit